# How can I add more pictures to the ImageSwitcher Timer?

Tags: android, imageview, imageswitcher

I want to put a timer on the `imageSwitcher` class. I was able to do that for 2 pictures using the following code, but I can't add more pictures. Can anyone tell me how can I add more pictures to the `ImageSwitcher` Timer?

```
imageSwitcher.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;
            public void run() {
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(
                    i++ % 2 == 0 ?
                        R.drawable.image1 :
                        R.drawable.mage2);
                imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this ? http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-slide-show.html

Comment: i just want to knw that how can i take more than 2 arguments in ImageSwitcher.setImageResource

or how can i add more pics to it ?

Comment: adding pics is discussed in setImagesToFlipper() of the link

Answer (score 1):

you can store in array

```
private static final int[] imgs = {R.drawable.image1,
                        R.drawable.mage2,
                        R.drawable.image3,
                        R.drawable.mage4};
```

then use this array by using index variable of and integer to get the drawable as you want. For e.g. you want to display circle slide so it start with 0 and when it reached to end it'll start from beginning

```
private int index = 0;

imageSwitcher.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imgs[index]);
                if(index==(imgs.length-1))
                     index = 0;
                else
                     index++;
                imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```